# Validate Attribute without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

In Rails 3, I would like to see if a value for an attribute is valid using the model's `validates` options without trying to save or create.

I'm writing the back end of a AJAX API, that should check a username against the

```
validates :username, :length => {:minimum => 2, :maximum => 50}, :exclusion => {:in => RESERVED_USERNAMES}, :format => MY_REGEX, .etc
```

In the User model. This it to create a little tick or cross next to the username field in the register form, so the user doesn't have to wait to see if the username is taken or not.

I could just compare it to a regex, but to try to keep my code DRY, I thought it would be better to use the validation in the user model.

Anyone know how I could do something of the line of:

```
username = params[:username]

if User.not_found(:username => username) && User.validate(:username => username)
    #yay!
else
    #nope
end
```

(I already have the `not_found` working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try checking for specific errors related to the username, in addition to running all validations (you need to in order to get the error messages).

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.invalid? && @user.errors[:username].any?
  # yay!
else
  # nope
end
```

You can run that without persisting your user to the database, since none of the methods used (including #new and #valid?) actually save the object.

Comment: That requires that I create a user object, with all the other attributes (like email, password, etc.), otherwise it will just return false every time because the other attribute validations will fail, right?

Comment: I would change the && for an 'and' and @user.errors.include? with @user.errors[:username].any?

Comment: You can use `@user.invalid?` instead of `@user.valid? == false`

Comment: Thanks, @Koen. Edited the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new user with username param and then inspect errors:

```
@user = User.new( :username => params[:username] )
@user.valid?    

if @user.errors.include? :username
  # username error
end
```

Comment: you need to call valid? first to trigger validations, also, it's better to check @user.errors[:username].any? instead

Comment: sorry, yes you need to call valid?